# Live calculate time from inputs

Tags: javascript, php

Question: so im doing a timesheet and i have 3 inputs with start, end and break and would like to do a live calculate with it but it need to be with a  `:` i have found some live calculator but non of them is time based and can take `:`

so the question how would i do it?

so this is what i got but it does not do time `:`
http://jsfiddle.net/5xzSy/1848/

Example: `08:00`(start)`10:00`(end)`01:00`(break) and that would be `01:00`(total)

so end-start-break=total

Comment: how about split on the colon, convert to minutes, run the math and convert back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var start = $('#start'),
  end = $('#end'),
  brk = $('#break'),
  total = $('#added'),
  timespan;

$('input').keyup(function() { // run anytime the value changes
  var e = toMins(end.val()),
    s = toMins(start.val()),
    b = toMins(brk.val());
  if (!s || !e) return;
  var output = (e - s - b) / 60;
  total.html(Math.floor(output) + ':' + toDouble(Math.round((output % 1) * 60)));
});

function toMins(val) {
  if (!val) return 0;
  val = val.split(':');
  return (Number(val[0]) * 60) + Number(val[1] || 0);
}

function toDouble(n) {
    return n < 10 ? ('0' + n) : n;
}
```

```css
table { margin: 10px; }
  table td { padding: 2px 4px; }
  input { width: 60px; padding: 2px 4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>Start:</td><td><input id=start placeholder="hh:mm"></td></tr>
<tr><td>End:</td><td><input id=end placeholder="hh:mm"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Break:</td><td><input id=break placeholder="hh:mm"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Total:</td><td><span id=added></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: okey so i dont know why but when i try to add it to my site it wont work :S

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/39ff950786eb03a4dd8c7577552afd6c it wont calculate, i tested other js code and that works :S

Comment: also when i try inside fiddle it works so i dont know what is wrong :(

Comment: sry i comment so much but i found something wierd about it like this 10:00(start)10:15(end)00:10(brk) = 00:05(total) but it shows like this 0:5(total)is there a way to get this format 00:05

Comment: modified my answer, added new function `toDouble` to add leading zeros

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you tu use a framework like Angular or VueJS that make that kind of requirements easier

https://vuejs.org/

https://angular.io/